# AutoIt how to unhide initial window with singleton

Tags: user-interface, window, autoit, window-handles

I have a singleton application that can be minimized to the system tray. It can happen that the user starts another instance of the application, and with `_singleton` I detect the first instance of the script and I activate the window before exiting the new instance.

However when the first instance is hidden with `GUISetState(@SW_HIDE)` the first instance is not showing up. I tried to get the window handle, but no success.

How can I unhide the first instance?

Consider the below code snippet:

```
If _Singleton("MyApp.exe", 1) = 0 Then
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, WinGetHandle("MyApp.exe"))
    WinActivate("MyApp")
    Exit
EndIf
```

Answer (score 0):

WinGetHandle() does not take an exe name as a parameter. It takes a window title. You could give your hidden window a unique name that isn't likely to be used by another application and use that to get the handle.

Or you could try using [_WinAPI_RegisterWindowMessage()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_WinAPI_RegisterWindowMessage.htm) in a simplified version of the code [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/127713-connect-two-program/) or [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/88166-communication-between-scripts/) to send a message from one instance of your application to the other instance which could unhide the window.